# Making div content look smaller with CSS

Tags: css

I want to make content of `<div class="features">` smaller so that it appears like this:
 [image: example image] 
Check this demo [here](http://www.servergreek.com/) to see what I have been able to achieve so far.As you see in the pic the features icons(No daily limits etc...) are small and the text below them is centered but I haven't been able to do this so far.

Comment: *...what?*  Do you mean changing the font size?  Maybe adding padding to make the content feel "smaller" inside the element?  Also, please post some code, don't just link to the root of your personal website.

Comment: No not the `font-size` won't affect the size of the features icons.You can just view the source `main.css` is the css i am talking about

Comment: I can't access your site behind my corporate firewall because it's marked as a botnet, unfortunately.

Comment: if you're talking about the images, `.features img` should be the selector to control the image sizes.

Comment: @Brodie i tried adding the `font-size` in `.features img` using inspect element but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: This question shows little or no research and is not useful or clear. See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Give Some **Width**  to class **features** in css .

```
<pre>
.features {  width: 800px; }
</pre>
```

You can use **media query** for this.(If device size is smaller then you mentioned as above then what will be size of your given width and all thing goes here...As shown below.)

```
<pre>
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
// font-size , margin , padding etc goes here ...

    }
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable `width` in the class `.feature`. Currently, it is set to `400px`. Once done, you should have something like this

[image: What you get]

Comment: the `.features` do not contain any width , do a Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

I figured, rather than go back and forth in comments, I'd just write an answer.

A couple of things to consider:

1. your images and your text are in separate areas. For the images you adjust their size using width/height not font-size. If you want to adjust the font-size then adjust the class of the captions.

   ```
   .features img {
     float: left;
     padding-left: 50px;
     width: 100px; /*add some sort of width/height and that will resize*/
   }
   ```
2. Your images and text are in different rows of the table, so adjusting them as a unit will be very hard.

   ```
   <tr>
     <td>
       <img src=""/>
       <p>text</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
   ```

would probably be a better set up, but to be honest ditching the tables all together and moving to a list would be more semantic.

```
<ul class="features">
  <li>
     <img src=""/>
     <span>image caption</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you really want to get semantic checkout http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/ but long story short, you just need to hit those images with a width/height to adjust the size.